# Detect iOS pointer capture bug for polyfilling

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

As reported in the [WebKit Bugilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=220196), iOS 13-15.4 seems to have a bug when trying to use pointer capture on touch and stylus inputs. (This was mostly fixed in iOS 15.5.) The problem is that calling `setPointerCapture` doesn't actually redirect future events when called on an element that was not the event's original target. However, calling `hasPointerCapture` will still work and return `true` as expected. Is there any way I would be able to feature test for this problem in order to implement a polyfill for it?

I created [a demo for this problem](https://thatcomputerguy0101.github.io/iOS_pointerCapture_bug/index.html) on GitHub if it helps. The green and yellow divs will correctly track the pointer movement if the pointer starts on the respective element, but the orange div should act the same and the red div should never move. Both of the latter will still track the pointer as long as the pointer remains over the divs.

The code that I currently have for polyfilling the bug is as below. It works, but its detection procedure is a UA string test and therefore won't work in the other iOS browsers even though they share the same JavaScript engine.

```js
// Need to figure out some way to test if this is needed.

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/1[345]\.\d+(?:\.\d+)? Safari/)) {
  const {
    setPointerCapture: set,
    hasPointerCapture: has,
    releasePointerCapture: release
  } = Element.prototype

  let targets = {},
      captures = {}

  Element.prototype.setPointerCapture = function setPointerCapture(pointerId) {
    if (pointerId in captures) {
      if (document.contains(this)) {
        captures[pointerId] = this
        return set.call(targets[pointerId], pointerId)
      } else {
        throw new TypeError("Element not in valid location")
      }
    } else {
      return set.call(this, pointerId)
    }
  }
  Element.prototype.hasPointerCapture = function hasPointerCapture(pointerId) {
    if (pointerId in captures) {
      return captures[pointerId] == this
    } else {
      return has.call(this, pointerId)
    }
  }
  Element.prototype.releasePointerCapture = function releasePointerCapture(pointerId) {
    if (pointerId in captures) {
      if (this.hasPointerCapture(pointerId)) {
        captures[pointerId] = null
        return release.call(targets[pointerId], pointerId)
      }
    } else {
      return release.call(this, pointerId)
    }
  }

  let registerPointer = function registerPointer(event) {
        if (event.pointerType == "touch" || event.pointerType == "pen") {
          targets[event.pointerId] = event.target
          captures[event.pointerId] = null
        }
      },
      redirectPointer = function redirectPointer(event) {
        if (captures[event.pointerId] != null && captures[event.pointerId] != event.target) {
          // Stop the original event
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()

          // Redispatch a new, cloned event
          captures[event.pointerId].dispatchEvent(new PointerEvent(event.type, event))
        }
      },
      redirectAndUnregisterPointer = function redirectAndUnregisterPointer(event) {
        redirectPointer(event)
        delete targets[event.pointerId]
        delete captures[event.pointerId]
      }

  addEventListener("pointerdown", registerPointer, {capture: true, passive: true})
  addEventListener("pointermove", redirectPointer, {capture: true, passive: false})
  addEventListener("pointerup", redirectAndUnregisterPointer, {capture: true, passive: false})
  addEventListener("pointercancel", redirectAndUnregisterPointer, {capture: true, passive: false})
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to give thanks for documenting this and updating to include iOS 15. I've been wondering about this behaviour for a long time but only yesterday realised what was going on. I mostly get the `pointerdown` event on the element I also want the capture for but then once in a while I get the event in the parent element and try to set the capture on the child element. And then the child might miss out on the `pointerup` event.

Comment: I've encountered this in iOS 14 but most frustratingly find my element that supposedly has capture receiving pointerup. 
Also stupid question but why the need for perfect detection? If you detect incorrectly and use the polyfill is there any harm?

Comment: Wrongly using the polyfill lowers performance without any benefit, but the bigger problem is not using the polyfill on iOS non-Safari browsers (Chrome for example).